# Однородны ли прилагательные "быстрые" и "точные" (решения)?

Tags: пунктуация, прилагательные, однородные-члены

*Необходимость принятия **быстрых точных** решений.*

Здесь прилагательные однородные или нет? Запятая вроде нужна, но характеристика ведь с разных сторон...

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, всё-таки однородные,характеристика с разных сторон, но одинаково положительна (быстрые, точные, верные - необходимые качества решений в какой-либо трудной ситуации), их объединяет отношение автора, можно поставить союз И, запятая нужна.